# How to set tokens in metrix nltk

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have two strings

```
str1= '12-January-2018 10:58:23 AM DEBUG [connection/Util]:loading db-engine-conf.yml DEBUG'

str2=  '12-January-2018 10:59:21 AM ERROR [connection/Util]:loading db-engine-conf.yml'
```

is there any functionality for matching this strings in Tensorflow??

if i use some `nltk` functions and get 80% similarity but i want to do this with tensorflow

```
        from nltk.corpus import stopwords 
        from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize 

        X= '12-January-2018 10:58:23 AM DEBUG [connection/Util]:loading db-engine-conf.yml'
        Y= '12-January-2018 10:59:21 AM ERROR [connection/Util]:loading db-engine-conf.yml'


        # tokenization 
        X_list = word_tokenize(X)  
        Y_list = word_tokenize(Y) 

        # sw contains the list of stopwords 
        sw = stopwords.words('english')  
        l1 =[];l2 =[] 

        # remove stop words from string 
        X_set = {w for w in X_list if not w in sw}  
        Y_set = {w for w in Y_list if not w in sw} 


        rvector = X_set.union(Y_set)  

        # form a set containing keywords of both strings  
        for w in rvector: 
             # create a vector 
            if w in X_set: l1.append(1)
            else: l1.append(0) 
            if w in Y_set: l2.append(1) 
            else: l2.append(0) 
        c = 0

        # cosine formula  
        for i in range(len(rvector)): 
                c+= l1[i]*l2[i] 
        cosine = c / float((sum(l1)*sum(l2))**0.5) 
        print("similarity: ", cosine)
```

suggest me an solution

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Please post your code?

Comment: @James please take a Look

Comment: @James now can i do that with TensorFlow?